# During install web3 package i occur unsolvable problem

Tags: python, web3py

I am lack of patience for this problem. I try to install web3 package for python. Every time I have tried to do this i occur abocve problem.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\kacpe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1b8hkvzx\\lru-dict_3fcca7cc367c4300b9aabe9030e66f5f\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\kacpe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1b8hkvzx\\lru-dict_3fcca7cc367c4300b9aabe9030e66f5f\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\kacpe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-1wp32ebv'
       cwd: C:\Users\kacpe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1b8hkvzx\lru-dict_3fcca7cc367c4300b9aabe9030e66f5f\
  Complete output (65 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 275, in _msvc14_get_vc_env
      out = subprocess.check_output(
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 424, in check_output
      return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 528, in run
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'cmd /u /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64 && set' returned non-zero exit status 255.

  The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\kacpe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1b8hkvzx\lru-dict_3fcca7cc367c4300b9aabe9030e66f5f\setup.py", line 6, in <module>
      setup (name = 'lru-dict',
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 155, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      return run_commands(dist)
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 163, in run_commands
      dist.run_commands()
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 79, in run
      _build_ext.run(self)
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 186, in run
      _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 195, in build_extensions
      _build_ext.build_ext.build_extensions(self)
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
      self._build_extensions_serial()
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 473, in _build_extensions_serial     
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 202, in build_extension
      _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 528, in build_extension
      objects = self.compiler.compile(sources,
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 327, in compile
      self.initialize()
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 224, in initialize
      vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 316, in msvc14_get_vc_env
      return _msvc14_get_vc_env(plat_spec)
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 280, in _msvc14_get_vc_env
      raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(
  setuptools._distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lru-dict
  Running setup.py clean for lru-dict
  Building wheel for bitarray (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\kacpe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1b8hkvzx\\bitarray_aefdbe80432a43a98706ce4864c2dc80\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\kacpe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1b8hkvzx\\bitarray_aefdbe80432a43a98706ce4864c2dc80\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\kacpe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-ijq099mp'
       cwd: C:\Users\kacpe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1b8hkvzx\bitarray_aefdbe80432a43a98706ce4864c2dc80\
  Complete output (71 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bitarray
  copying bitarray\test_bitarray.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bitarray
  copying bitarray\test_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bitarray
  copying bitarray\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bitarray
  copying bitarray\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bitarray
  running build_ext
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 275, in _msvc14_get_vc_env
      out = subprocess.check_output(
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 424, in check_output
      return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 528, in run
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'cmd /u /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64 && set' returned non-zero exit status 255.

  The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\kacpe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1b8hkvzx\bitarray_aefdbe80432a43a98706ce4864c2dc80\setup.py", line 18, in <module>
      setup(
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      return run_commands(dist)
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 163, in run_commands
      dist.run_commands()
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 79, in run
      _build_ext.run(self)
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 186, in run
      _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 195, in build_extensions
      _build_ext.build_ext.build_extensions(self)
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
      self._build_extensions_serial()
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 473, in _build_extensions_serial     
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 202, in build_extension
      _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 528, in build_extension
      objects = self.compiler.compile(sources,
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 327, in compile
      self.initialize()
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 224, in initialize
      vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 316, in msvc14_get_vc_env
      return _msvc14_get_vc_env(plat_spec)
    File "c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 280, in _msvc14_get_vc_env
      raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(
  setuptools._distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for bitarray
  Running setup.py clean for bitarray
  Building wheel for cytoolz (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\kacpe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1b8hkvzx\\cytoolz_97416e26c0be440fb7f02f80b7d7709f\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\kacpe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1b8hkvzx\\cytoolz_97416e26c0be440fb7f02f80b7d7709f\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from 
setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\kacpe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-0453le_v'
       cwd: C:\Users\kacpe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1b8hkvzx\cytoolz_97416e26c0be440fb7f02f80b7d7709f\
  Complete output (52 lines):
  [1/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/utils.pyx
  [2/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/dicttoolz.pyx
  [3/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/functoolz.pyx
  [4/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/itertoolz.pyx
  [5/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/recipes.pyx
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\compatibility.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\_signatures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\curried
  copying cytoolz\curried\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\curried
  copying cytoolz\curried\operator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\curried
  copying cytoolz\curried\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\curried
  copying cytoolz\dicttoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\functoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\itertoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\recipes.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\utils.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\cpython.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\dicttoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\functoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\itertoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\recipes.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\utils.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\dev_skip_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_compatibility.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_curried.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_curried_toolzlike.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_dev_skip_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_dicttoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_docstrings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_doctests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_embedded_sigs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_functoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_inspect_args.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_itertoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_none_safe.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_recipes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_serialization.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_signatures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_tlz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
  running build_ext
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cytoolz
  Running setup.py clean for cytoolz
Failed to build lru-dict bitarray cytoolz
Installing collected packages: cytoolz, eth-utils, varint, rlp, pycryptodome, parsimonious, netaddr, multidict, hexbytes, frozenlist, eth-keys, base58, yarl, multiaddr, 
eth-rlp, eth-keyfile, eth-abi, charset-normalizer, bitarray, async-timeout, aiosignal, websockets, lru-dict, ipfshttpclient, eth-account, aiohttp
    Running setup.py install for cytoolz ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\kacpe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1b8hkvzx\\cytoolz_97416e26c0be440fb7f02f80b7d7709f\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\kacpe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1b8hkvzx\\cytoolz_97416e26c0be440fb7f02f80b7d7709f\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 
'C:\Users\kacpe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-j4h7_gap\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\cytoolz'
         cwd: C:\Users\kacpe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1b8hkvzx\cytoolz_97416e26c0be440fb7f02f80b7d7709f\
    Complete output (54 lines):
    [1/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/utils.pyx
    [2/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/dicttoolz.pyx
    [3/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/functoolz.pyx
    [4/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/itertoolz.pyx
    [5/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/recipes.pyx
    running install
    c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\compatibility.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\_signatures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\curried\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\curried\operator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\curried\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\dicttoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\functoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\itertoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\recipes.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\utils.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\cpython.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\dicttoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\functoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\itertoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\recipes.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\utils.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\dev_skip_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_compatibility.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_curried.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_curried_toolzlike.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_dev_skip_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_dicttoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_docstrings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_doctests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_embedded_sigs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_functoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_inspect_args.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_itertoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_none_safe.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_recipes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_serialization.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_signatures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_tlz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    running build_ext
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\kacpe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1b8hkvzx\\cytoolz_97416e26c0be440fb7f02f80b7d7709f\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\kacpe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1b8hkvzx\\cytoolz_97416e26c0be440fb7f02f80b7d7709f\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\kacpe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-j4h7_gap\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\kacpe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\cytoolz' Check the logs for full command output.
```

What I already done:

- Pip upgrade
- Uninstall Microsoft Visual C++ from widnows
- Install Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 from official site (Microsoft C++ Build Tools) and then uninstall and install again,
- Try to install this at Python 3.9 and 3.10
- System Windows 10

Of course when i install web3 without dependencies everything is ok, but this is not acceptable for project i want to do.

Do you have any idea what can fix this?